# Android: Asynchronous process using AsyncTask for connecting to internet

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask

For my Android app I need to call a web page from activity, and wait until a response is received from remote server. So I think I need to use a new thread. Can I use AsynkTask? How can I tell to my activity that it must wait for respose to AsynkTask process?

Comment: yes you can use AsyncTask.

Comment: Ok, but the other question is: "ow can I tell to my activity that it must wait for respose to AsynkTask process?"

Comment: What do you want to do while you are waiting for the response?

Comment: Nothing, the information retrived from internet are strictly required for continuing the application execuiting. Maybe I will use a Progressbar

Answer (score 0):

check [asyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

And you can use callbacks to inform the activity that the task has finished
check https://stackoverflow.com/a/13947857/1434631

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `AsyncTask`

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) has a method called `onPostExecute()` which lets you know when your background process, in this case, loading data from server, is completed.

[Here](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/) is a nice tutorial !