# Why do I get a null pointer exception while issuing a HTTP request using AsyncTask in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, request

I'm trying to get scoreboards from FB, and to achieve this I issue a HTTP request to the API. It has to be done on a separate thread, here is my async task class:

```
public class AsyncBuildScoreboard extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,String> {
ProgressBar pb;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    String token = Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken();     
    try{            
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();                
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://graph.facebook.com/"+GameStatic.app_id+"?fields=scores&access_token=" + token);
        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(get);                    
        HttpEntity responseEntity = resp.getEntity();
        String response = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);     
        return response;

    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {

    }   
    return "";

}


protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
    try{    
        JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);                          
        JSONObject scores = res.getJSONObject("scores");
        JSONArray data = scores.getJSONArray("data");                       
        int len = data.length();                        
        String[] values = new String[len];
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(i);                         
            JSONObject user = obj.getJSONObject("user");
            String name = user.getString("name");
            String score = obj.getString("score");          
            values[i] = name + "  " + score;
            GameStatic.scoreboard.add(values[i]);
        }
    }       
    catch (JSONException e)
    {

    }



}

}
```

GameStatic is an external variable to store what I get from thread. And yet, when doing this:

```
AsyncBuildScoreboard board = new AsyncBuildScoreboard ();
    board.execute();        
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scorelist);            
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, GameStatic.scoreboard);        
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

a null pointer exception occurs, which means, that the GameStatic.scoreboard has NOT been filled with the entries I wanted.

What am I doing wrong, any ideas?

I'd be obliged, since I am REALLY pressed on time...

```
public class AsyncBuildScoreboard extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
public ListView list;
public Context ctx;
public ArrayList<String> scoreboard = new ArrayList <String> ();


public AsyncBuildScoreboard(ListView list, Context context)
{
    this.list = list;
    this.ctx = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) 
{
    Void nothing = null;
    String token = Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken();     
    try{            
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();                
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://graph.facebook.com/"+GameStatic.app_id+"?fields=scores&access_token=" + token);
        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(get);                    
        HttpEntity responseEntity = resp.getEntity();
        String response = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity); 


    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {

    }   
    return nothing;     
}


protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
    try{    
        JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);                          
        JSONObject scores = res.getJSONObject("scores");
        JSONArray data = scores.getJSONArray("data");                       
        int len = data.length();                        
        String[] values = new String[len];
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(i);                         
            JSONObject user = obj.getJSONObject("user");
            String name = user.getString("name");
            String score = obj.getString("score");          
            values[i] = name + "  " + score;
            scoreboard.add(values[i]);
        }
    }       
    catch (JSONException e)
    {

    }
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ctx,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, scoreboard);       
    list.setAdapter(adapter); 


}



}
```

Comment: Can you copy your response string?

Comment: return response; after catch block. remove return ""; and try the suggested answer by @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: you need to notifyDatasetChanged when you modify the array backing your listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use `onPostExecute` for showing the score when `doInBackground` execution complete instead of passing `GameStatic.scoreboard` just after `AsyncTask.execute()` because `doInBackground` always execute in separate thread so it.

you can use  `AsyncBuildScoreboard` class constructor for passing ListView instance and Context from Activity as:

```
ListView listview;
Context context;
public AsyncBuildScoreboard(ListView listview,Context context){
 this.context=context;
 this.listview=listview;
}
....
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
   //...your code here..

  StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(context,
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, GameStatic.scoreboard);        
    listview.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

and change your Activity code as for passing Context :

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scorelist);
AsyncBuildScoreboard board = new AsyncBuildScoreboard (listview,
                                                     Your_Activity.this);
board.execute();
```

or you can also create callbacks methods using interface which fire when on UI Thread when doInBackground execution complete.see following post for more details:

[android asynctask sending callbacks to ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui)

Comment: Thanks, that looks very reasonable, though I get an error of undefined constructor, even though I did define it in the asynctask class...

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski : ok plz show your latest updated code to get more help

Comment: there you go. now there is no error, but my array remains empty

Comment: ok... I'll try, but why did you put the ArrayAdapter instance inside the for loop?

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski : bez if any error occur in json parsing then ArrayAdapter code not execute and you can change it according to your need

Comment: nvm, it works!!!! thanks a lot you saved my ass man! really, I would be sooo screwed without that... thanks!