# ListView Scroll To Bottom with AsynTask on Image

Tags: android, image, android-listview, image-scaling

Problem: `ListView` Cannot Scroll To Bottom when Image(s) are loaded using `AsynTask`.

Details: I want to scroll the listView to bottom when user opens the listView. The listview contains both images and text. For better memory managemt, i am using the method suggested [here](http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/), which shows a small icon when the bitmap is loading.

In order to scroll to bottom, I used"

```
`listview.setStackFromBottom(true);`
```

and:

```
listView.setSelection(adapter.getCount()-1);
```

However, for images listview, it just can't scroll to bottom. Is there any solutions for this issue?

[image]

Comment: Try to add `android:stackFromBottom="true"` and `android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"` in your litview layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out the root of the problem.
When you are loading images in listView using "AsyncTask", you need to use

```
listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS);
```

My listview cannot scroll to the bottom as i set

```
listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

which leads to the problem discussed above.

Answer (score 1):

your `AsyncTask` `onPostExecute` should look something like this

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(adapter!=null && commentList.size()>0){
            adapter=new ImageAdapter((Activity) activity, imageList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            scrollListViewToBottom();
        }
    }
```

and then the method `scrollListViewToBottom()`

```
    private void scrollListViewToBottom() {
    listView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
            listView.setSelection(adapter.getCount());
        }
    });
}
```

and you are done :)

Comment: I don't use the ImageAdapter. Instead, the getView of adapter will get the imagepath and i use a new AsyncTask to load it into bitmap. I have thought of using your method but i don't know how to know when my last AsyncTask is finished....

Comment: 1) There is no such thing as ImageAdapter, it was only for your reference. This can work with any adapter (Baseadapter, Arrayadapter)
2) onPostExecute method of asynctask you can check (this)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492641/get-the-result-from-async-task]

Answer (score 0):

use `android:stackFromBottom="true"` in your listview xml layout.

For example,

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:stackFromBottom="true" >
</ListView>
```

Hope this works fine.