# Get the Result from a list of Task

Tags: asynchronous, lambda, asp.net-core, async-await, task

I know this has been asked before, but I simply cannot figure out how to do this right.

So, the below code is obviously wrong in the sense that I am `await`ing something in a query.

```
    // GET: /<controller>/
    [HttpGet]
    public new IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new List<Models.ViewModels.ApplicationUser.ListViewModel>();
        model = _userManager.Users.Select(u => new Models.ViewModels.ApplicationUser.ListViewModel
        {
            Id = u.Id,
            Email = u.Email,
            Name = u.GivenName + " " + u.SurName,
            RoleNames = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(u)
        }).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

This makes the following error show: "the "await" operator can only be used within an async lambda expression".

So, I finalize the query first and I make the lambda async:

```
    // GET: /<controller>/
    [HttpGet]
    public new IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new List<Models.ViewModels.ApplicationUser.ListViewModel>();
        // get users first, so I don't have to async something in a Select
        var users = _userManager.Users.ToList();
        // make the lambda asyc
        model = users.Select(async u => new Models.ViewModels.ApplicationUser.ListViewModel
        {
            Id = u.Id,
            Email = u.Email,
            Name = u.GivenName + " " + u.SurName,
            RoleNames = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(u)
        }).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

But then I get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Models.ViewModels.ApplicationUser.ListViewModel>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.ViewModels.ApplicationUser.ListViewModel>'`

So basically (I guess) it says I have a list of `Task` of which I should get the result. But how do I get the result from this `Task`? Or better: what is the best way to go about this?

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768284/the-await-operator-can-only-be-used-with-an-async-lambda-expression) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492641/get-the-result-from-async-task) and [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) without getting closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable named `model` is of the type `List<Task<ApplicationUser>>`. To get a `List<ApplicationUser>` you just need to `await` all of the tasks. Also, right now the call to get all users is the blocking variant you can switch that out for `ToListAsync`. Try this instead:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index() {
    var model = new List<Models.ViewModels.ApplicationUser.ListViewModel>();
    // get users first, so I don't have to async something in a Select
    var users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
    // make the lambda asyc
    modelTasks = users.Select(async u => new Models.ViewModels.ApplicationUser.ListViewModel {
        Id = u.Id,
        Email = u.Email,
        Name = u.GivenName + " " + u.SurName,
        RoleNames = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(u)
    }).ToList();
    var users = await Task.WhenAll(modelTasks);
    return View(users);
}
```