# Asynctask (execute from alarmmanager) callbacks to ui

Tags: android, callback, android-asynctask

I'm having an issue with this one.
My app has some **asynctasks that are execute by an alarmmanager** (like an alarm clock). I want that when this task is running, if the user is using the **mainactivity** of the app, a **indeterminate progress** bar shows.

I saw this post :
[android asynctask sending callbacks to ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui)

That uses an interface. But as it's not my activity which execute the task, I can't register the listener in the `asynctask`.

So, I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: so where do you invoke asynctask if not in activity?

Comment: **"execute by an alarmmanager (like an alarm clock)."** - When you say "alarmmanager" do you actually mean an alarm created by the Android `AlarmManager` service or something else?

Comment: Yes, i'm using the android alarmanager to run the asynctask every hour to reach for data in the web.
I do invoke the alarmmanger from the activity the first time. But then, the user can quit the activity and come back days after.

Comment: To me more specific, the alarmmanager trigers a broadcast that i receive on a broadcastreceiverclass and then the asynctask is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I'd recommend using an `IntentService` instead of an `AsyncTask`.

Secondly, create an inner class in your main activity which extends `BroadcastReceiver`.

Register an instance of the inner `BroadcastReceiver` in `onResume()` of your `Activity` and unregister it in `onPause()`.

Have your first `BroadcastReceiver` start the `IntentService` and have the `IntentService` send a broadcast which the inner `BroadcastReceiver` of your `Activity` will be listening for if the `Activity` is running - the inner `BroadcastReceiver` can then create the progress bar.

When the `IntentService` finishes what it needs to do get it to send another broadcast to indicate that the progress bar should be dismissed.