# changing marker icon in Async Task onPostExecute method

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to add custom marker in an Async Task class inside onPostExecute method. But when I tried the change marker icon ".icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.)", the image that I coppied to drawable folders is not visible in that method. What could be the problem?

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jobject) {        

    try { 

        // ...

        MarkerOptions bingTrafficMarker = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(positionLatLng)
            .title(strdescription);

        gm.addMarker(bingTrafficMarker); 

        // ...            
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you change the marker icon ?

Comment: after ".title(strdescription)" just writing ".icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.)". But this line doesn't work because my image in the drawable folder is not visible.

Comment: it must be visible like that "R.drawable.my_image"

Answer (score 0):

I used an callback method in the onPostExecute to let me get back to my main class.

Here is what I did

Code of the AsyncTask

```
class AsyncRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

public interface OnTaskCompleted {

    public abstract void findGeoCode(Document resultCode, String direction);
}

private OnTaskCompleted listener;

public AsyncRequest(OnTaskCompleted listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Document result) {
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.findGeoCode(result, direction);
    }
}
```

Code of the main class that implement the interface callback

```
private OnTaskCompleted listener = new OnTaskCompleted() {
    @Override
    public void findGeoCode(Document resultCode, String direction) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LatLng cord = getLocateAddress(resultCode);
    }
```

The calling method

```
new AsyncRequest(listener).execute(paras)
```

Hope this help

Comment: These 2 links are well explained about my solution above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui   and  http://android-er.blogspot.com.au/2013/09/implement-callback-function-with.html

Comment: thanks for your contribution but unfortunately this doesn't help my condition.