# How to pass the return value of an AsyncTask callback to another class properly without get() method?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, callback, return-value

In my application I need to call a web service to get some data from the internet. To avoid blocking the UI I use an `AsyncTask` to do that. But I'm having problems to pass the return value correctly for further use. I guess I'm making some architectural mistakes here. So this is how my application is/should be structured:

**`MainActivity`**: An `Activity` containing a `TextView`, a `Button` and a `SoapParser` (see below). I want to call the web service by pressing the `Button`, parse the result and display it in the `TextView`.

**`SoapRequestTask`**: An `AsyncTask` with a callback mechanism like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963705/1200849). The return value of `doInBackground()` is a `SoapObject` and is passed to the listener as a parameter in the callback method `listener.onTaskCompleted(SoapObject)` in `onPostExecute()`.

**`SoapRequestManager`**: A class that should have a method `public SoapObject makeRequest(someParams)`. This method is supposed to use my `AsyncTask` and return my `SoapObject` from its `doInBackground()`.

**`MySpecialRequestManager`**: Extends `SoapRequestManager` and has different methods to call the web service for different results. Each of these methods uses `makeRequest(someParams)` of the superclass.

**`SoapParser`**: A class that parses a `SoapObject` to a `String` so it can be displayed in my `Activity`'s `TextView`. It should have a method like `public String parseResult(SoapObject)`.

How do I use the callback  and the return value correctly? Which class should implement the callback interface?

Comment: Have SoapRequestManager implement BroadcastReceiver and send a broadcast that for it to receive that contains a bundle with the data in question.

Comment: @zgc7009 Could you please give me a code example?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick snippet because you asked for some code. This might help get you started

In the AsyncTask's postExecute() method in SoapRequestTask

```
Intent intent = new Intent("send_data");
intent.setAction("SEND_DATA");              // don't NEED this, as we implicitly
                                            // declare our intent during initialization
intent.putExtra("data_return_key", mData);  // where mData is what you want to return
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then for SoapRequestManager

```
public class SoapRequestManager implements BroadcastReceiver{
    int mData;                        // assuming our data is an int in this example

    // Default constructor
    public SoapRequestManager(){
        registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter("send_data"));
        // if you use setAction use the below registration instead
        // registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter("SEND_DATA"));
    }

    //... All of the stuff you have in the class already

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        // For this example let's say mData is an integer value

        // if you use setAction, check that the intent is the correct one via
        // if (intent.getAction().equals("SEND_DATA"))
        mData = intent.getIntExtra("data_return_key");
    }
}
```