# FragmentTabHost and Asynchronous Tasks

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-tabhost

**The Problem:**

I am trying to create two tabs containing `Fragments` with a `FragmentTabHost`.

Here is where I add the tabs to the `FragmentTabHost` (the `onCreate` method of the `FragmentActivity` that contains the tabs:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_financials);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_ONE).setIndicator("Tab #1",
                    getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
                    MyFragmentOne.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_TWO).setIndicator("Tab #2",
                    getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
                    MyFragmentTwo.class, null);


    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        new MyAsyncTask(MyClass.this).execute();    
    }
    else {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("TAB_TAG"));
    }

}
```

However, the problem is that both `MyFragmentOne` and `MyFragmentTwo` are waiting for data from `MyAsyncTask`. That is, the views in each fragment can only be created properly after `MyAsyncTask` has completed running.

So I end up getting a `NullPointerException` when I add the tabs because the required data hasn't been fetched by the `AsyncTask` yet.

**My Solution Attempt:**

I tried calling `TabHost#addTab()` in the `onPostExecute()` of `MyAsyncTask` so that the Fragments are only created **after** `MyAsyncTask` completes, thus avoiding any null pointers.

However, by moving the `addTab()` calls to `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`, I get the error: `No tab tag for null`. Logcat below.

**Logcat:**

```
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No tab known for tag null
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.doTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:330)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:280)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12585)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2458)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2465)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2465)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2465)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2465)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2465)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1217)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-06 06:15:17.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a blank `PlaceHolderFragment` and removing them programmatically in `onPostExecute()` like so:

```
mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("Placeholder one").setIndicator("Tab #1",
                    getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
                    PlaceHolderFragment.class, null);
mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("Placeholder two").setIndicator("Tab #2",
                    getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
                    PlaceHolderFragment.class, null);
```

Then in `onPostExecute()` :

```
mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
mTabHost.clearAllTabs();

mTabHost.addTab(
        mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_ONE).setIndicator("Tab #1",
                getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
                MyFragmentOne.class, null);
mTabHost.addTab(
        mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_TWO).setIndicator("Tab #2",
                getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
                MyFragmentTwo.class, null);
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any logic to your solution/ logcat error. Anyway congrats!! :)

Comment: Since it seems that I MUST add tabs in `onCreateView`, I add two dummy tabs that are empty. If I don't do this, then I get an `IllegalStateException`. Then, in my `AsyncTask`, once I fetch the required data from the server, it calls `onPostExecute()`, which removes the dummy tabs that contain blank Fragments, and adds the two tabs I need to put there. This way I get no `NullPointerException` either since the data has already been fetched by the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: it looks like this is the only possible solution if you really need to lazy load your tabHost content. You actually don't need to add two dummy tabs, one is enough but it looks like the tabHost can't be empty after the view is returned from onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AsyncTaks with a callback. Then in that callback you can create your tabs with the data.

For example:
[android asynctask sending callbacks to ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui)

This is just an example, there are a lot of examples using asyncTask and callbacks

Comment: A callback would still result in the same no tab tag for null error since it is essentially the same as having the asynchronous task nested in the fragment activity and implementing it's onpostexecute. (I tried using a callback earlier and got the same error)

Comment: Ok, you are right. Did you try to create the tabs with some dummy data?

Comment: Yeah, actually I tried just that and it worked great, i'll post it as an answer.