# Android: how to use JSOUP parser effectively

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I am using JSOUP HTML parser to parse HTML. I have one specific site like example.com/test.html. This site consists of several divs. At first load I need to load first div. Next I need to load div specified by selected value in spinner. So my question is: Is there a way to use async task to do `Jsoup.connect().get()` and then use this loaded document multiple times? I programmed it inside async task but then I realized that I cant use same async task multiple time.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in forward

Comment: Did you really mean to say JSON here - or is that just a typo for jsoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not java or android expert, but I will try to help.

**Basically - you have to learn what are callbacks/interfaces and how to use them.**

You have to store downloaded HTML by declaring `Document` object in your `Activity` class and add callback that will allow AsyncTask to update that document from "outside" `Activity` by another thread.

It is similar to updating UI with callback.

[android asynctask sending callbacks to ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui)