# HttpHostConnectException + NullPointerException

Tags: android, mysql, nullpointerexception, httphostconnectexception

I'm trying to get data from mySQL database on my machine. When i rum the app on the emulator i get a `HttpHostConnectException` (i have tested my address in a browser and tried 10.0.2.2 with and without the port number) then the app crashes with `NullPointerException`. What can I do fix these issue?

Connector.java

```
public class Connector {

public JSONArray getResults(){

    String url = "http://192.168.87.1/android/getStudents.php";

    HttpEntity httpentity = null;

    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient =new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget= new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();

    }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONArray jsonarray = null;
    if(httpentity != null){
        try{
            String entityresponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpentity);
            Log.e("Entity Response: ", entityresponse);

            jsonarray = new JSONArray(entityresponse);

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonarray;
}}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private TextView resultsViewer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.resultsViewer = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.resultsViewer);

    new getResultsTask().execute(new Connector());
}


private void setText (JSONArray jsonarray){

    String string = "";
    for(int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject json = null;
        try{
            json = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

            string = string + "Exam : " + json.getString("exam_name") + "\n" +
                              "Score :" + json.getString("score") + "\n\n";

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    this.resultsViewer.setText(string);
}

private class getResultsTask extends AsyncTask<Connector, Long, JSONArray>{

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Connector... params) {

                 return params[0].getResults();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonarray) {

        setText(jsonarray);
    }

}}
```

some lines from LogCat

```
Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f09003f}
 Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
 Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3259(270KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 31% free, 759KB/1117KB, paused 3.009ms total 1.004s
 org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.56.1 refused
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:188)
```

and the NullPointerExeption

```
    Shutting down VM
 --------- beginning of crash
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.ed.jsontest2, PID: 1302
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
    at com.ed.jsontest2.MainActivity.setText(MainActivity.java:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the ip address 10.0.0.2 , if the server is running in your local machine.the port number is necessary

your url should be http://10.0.2.2:portnumber/android/getStudents.php...

port number is your local server running port

if you are running the server from remote machin then replace the host ipaddress

Comment: I've made the change. I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: what is the port number of your service running ?  local machine or remote machine ?

Comment: first check http://localhost:80/android/getStudents.php from your browser ... if this is not working then the problem will be with your server side

Comment: It works in the browser but still not working in the app

Comment: Still no change. :(  what are we missing?

Comment: Solved - i added INTERNET permission to wrong Manifest file

Comment: now this is comming up  `03-27 13:42:25.081: E/Entity Response:(1953): [{"exam_name":"Tax","score":"75"},{"exam_name":"Law","score":"60"}]
` `03-27 13:42:25.101: D/AndroidRuntime(1953): Shutting down VM
03-27 13:42:25.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1953): FATAL EXCEPTION: main` `03-27 13:42:25.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1953): Process: com.ed.jsontest2, PID: 1953

` `03-27 13:42:25.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1953): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
`

Comment: @Joshua refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui ...callback from asynctask to mainthread to update the result in view

Comment: fixed this a while back. the textview did not have an id