# ProgressDialog in the main activity (not Asynctask)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

Since I need to get String array from the Asyntask, I need to use the get() after the execute():

```
String[] result = task.execute().get();
```

But I also want a loading circle while the task is running and the ProgressDialog only works if you don't use the get() method. This is confirmed, I've done some tests.
So I think the only option left here is to call the ProgressDiaglog from the MainActivity. But unluckily it doesn't work.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

never ever use `get()` with an asynctask, if you need to get something that was done in an asynctask you need to pass it to `onPostExecute` and use it there.

Using get() completely goes against what an asycntask is suppose to be for

Comment: I know, but what if the asynctask is an individual class and I need to get the String array in my main activity?

Comment: then you need to implement an `interface` that calls back to the class that started the task when the data is ready

Comment: Well, Im new to android, could you be more specific?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui