# Return value to a different Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, delegates

[image: app design]

I have an app that basically looks like the design in the attached picture.
As you can see, there are 4 activities, and some of the activities have fragments.

I want to get the answer of a test back to the user's profile.
Up to now, I've been uploading the result to the server and having the app update the user's profile every time they go back to the **ProfileActivity**, but that seems like a waste of resources.

Is there a pattern or way to do this in the app?
I looked at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html): which seems doable if I can somehow link two `startActivityForResult()`s.

I looked into using the delegate pattern described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui) but I can't get the instance of the **UserFragment** to the **TestActivity**.

I hope someone can point me in the direction of the correct way of doing this.

Comment: You can store User object in preferences. You can update that object when it's value have changed. Display user data which store in preferences in profile activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is use `startActivityForResult()` don't finish any `Activity`

start all activities by `startActivityForResult()` then depending on your condition you can finish activity

pass result back to the previous activity  using `onActivityResult()`

Then for fragment you can store fragment object in **ProfileActivity** .
In Fragment write method for updating UI

So you can access that method using fragment object

```
class ProfileActivity extends ......
{
  @override
  public void onActivityResult(....)
  {
    .....
    frgamnetObject.updateUI();
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm leaning towards this approach, but I have a question. The second activity (TestActivity), might continue after a test has been completed. Can I keep the activity open after sending back a result with setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)? Or do I have to call finish()?

Comment: You can keep running but best practice is to finish  because we want data to previous activity so front activity work is done.  Or if needed you can keep it running

Comment: OK, this works and seems like the most "Android" way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are getting one int value from last page:

create class :

```
public class GenericUtility {

public static int getIntFromSharedPrefsForKey(String key, Context context)
{
    int selectedValue = 0;

    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.your.packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    selectedValue = prefs.getInt(key, 0);

    return selectedValue;
}

public static boolean setIntToSharedPrefsForKey(String key, int value, Context context)
{
    boolean savedSuccessfully = false;

    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.your.packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    try
    {
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.apply();
        savedSuccessfully = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        savedSuccessfully = false;
    }

    return savedSuccessfully;
}

public static String getStringFromSharedPrefsForKey(String key, Context context)
{
    String selectedValue = "";

    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.your.packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    selectedValue = prefs.getString(key, "");

    return selectedValue;
}

public static boolean setStringToSharedPrefsForKey(String key, String value, Context context)
{
    boolean savedSuccessfully = false;

    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.your.packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    try
    {
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.apply();
        savedSuccessfully = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        savedSuccessfully = false;
    }

    return savedSuccessfully;
}
}
```

than to set int value to it:

```
GenericUtility.setIntToSharedPrefsForKey("selected_theme", 1, getApplicationContext());
```

or

```
GenericUtility.setIntToSharedPrefsForKey("selected_theme", 1, MyActivity.this))
```

and in your very first activity where you want result:

```
int selectedValue = GenericUtility.getIntFromSharedPrefsForKey("selected_theme", getApplicationContext());
```

or

```
int selectedValue = GenericUtility.getIntFromSharedPrefsForKey("selected_theme", MyActivity.this);
```

selectedValue will return default value if there is no value in it.
PS change int to String in class to get and set result accordingly.