# return json to activity by asynctask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, execute

I'm using a doInBackground method to get a json from a web service so I can use it in my main activity here's what I did but it doesn't work

```
public class JSONTransmitter extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> {
 @Override
 protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... data) {
 //.....    
    return json;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);

 }
}
```

and here is my main activity

```
public void sync(View v){
    LocationsDB mLocationsDB = new LocationsDB(SupportMapActivity.this);
    Cursor events= mLocationsDB.getAllLocations();

    try {
        JSONObject json=makJsonObject(events);
        JSONTransmitter transmitter = new JSONTransmitter();
        AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> jsonRetour = transmitter.execute(new JSONObject[]{json}); 
//I want to use it here like jsonRetour.getString("something");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: AsyncTask is asynchronous. You'll get the result back in onPostExecute().

Comment: possible duplicate of [android asynctask sending callbacks to ui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui)     Either use an Interface to enable a callback into your Activity, or just make the AsyncTask an inner class of the Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this but one of my favourite ways is with a callback interface.

Here is the JSONTransmitter:

```
public class JSONTransmitter extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> {

    private OnJsonTransmitionCompleted mCallback;

    public JSONTransmitter(OnJsonTransmitionCompleted callback) {
        this.mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... data) {
        //.....    
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
        this.mCallback.onTransmitionCompleted(jsonObject);
    }

    public interface OnJsonTransmitionCompleted {
        void onTransmitionCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject);
    }
}
```

The callback interface `OnJsonTransmitionCompleted` is inside the `JSONTrasnmitter` as its only use is with the `JSONTransmitter`.

Here is the main activity:

```
public class SupportMapActivity extends Activity implements JSONTransmitter.OnJsonTransmitionCompleted{

    public void sync(View v){
        LocationsDB mLocationsDB = new LocationsDB(SupportMapActivity.this);
        Cursor events= mLocationsDB.getAllLocations();

        try {
            JSONObject json = makJsonObject(events);
            JSONTransmitter transmitter = new JSONTransmitter(this);
            transmitter.execute(new JSONObject[]{json}); 

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransmitionCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        // Now you have access to your JSON data in your activity!
    }
}
```

So we create a callback interface inside the `JSONTransmitter` which has one method `void onTransmitionCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject)` that will pass the `JSONObject` to your activity from `onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject)`.

Inside the main activity we implement `JSONTransmitter.OnJsonTransmitionCompleted` and pass in `this` when we instantiate `JSONTransmitter` and lastly we Override `void onTransmitionCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject)` inside the activity and once our `AsyncTask` has finished its background process and `onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject)` has been called we will receive the `JSONObject` inside the implemented method `onTransmitionCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject)`.

I hope this helps here are a few links on this topic:

[android asynctask sending callbacks to ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui)

http://android-er.blogspot.co.il/2013/09/implement-callback-function-with.html

http://blog.redkitmedia.com/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui/

http://android-dwivediji.blogspot.co.il/2014/01/best-way-to-use-asynctask-class.html

Answer (score 0):

In the JSONTransmitter, you need to do something with the JSON object in the onPostExecute(). At the moment, your Async task does nothing with it.

Try this:

In the Main activity, have a JSONObject var called mJson and in your onPostExecute do this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
  super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
  mJson = jsonObject;
  // call a method from the MainActivity to do whatever needs to be done with the JSON
}
```

Of course for this to work, the AsyncTask must be an inner class on the Main Activity.