# Android get activity from within anonymous class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm super new to Android development and Java in general. Here's the basic setup: I have a splash screen with an `AsyncTask` to check server availability. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui) thread I made a callback in my activity. This makes more sense than doing the work in `OnPostExecute()` as I want to reuse this task in different activities.

However, in my callback I do a check if the status is okay. If it is, it should launch the next activity. But from the context of my callback, I don't get how I can get my `Activity` reference, which I need as a parameter for the Intent.

This is the code in my Activity under OnCreate:

```
    //Check server status
    CheckServiceTask t = new CheckServiceTask(new OnTaskCompleted<ShaggyServiceStatus>() {
        @Override
        public void onTaskCompleted(ShaggyServiceStatus result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Callback. Result: " + result.getStatus());
            ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.splash_progress);
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if (result.getStatusCode() == 999){
                TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.splash_status_text);
                t.setText(result.getStatus());
                return;
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
    });

    t.execute();
```

The part where this fails is at `getActivity()`. That call is not available. Using `this` throws an error (which I understand, as I'm in the context of `OnTaskCompleted`).

For completeness, this is the interface for OnTaskCompleted:

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted<T> {
    public void onTaskCompleted(T result);
}
```

And this is the CheckServiceTask class:

```
public class CheckServiceTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ShaggyServiceStatus>{
    private static final String TAG = "coo";

    public OnTaskCompleted<ShaggyServiceStatus> listener;

    public CheckServiceTask (OnTaskCompleted<ShaggyServiceStatus> l){
        this.listener = l;
    }

    @Override
    protected ShaggyServiceStatus doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connecting to server...");
            //TODO: Make this a setting
            final String url = "https://someplace.com/status";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            //restTemplate.postForObject("url", bodyObject, ShaggySer.class);
            ShaggyServiceStatus sss = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ShaggyServiceStatus.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "Got the status.");
            return sss;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO: Exception handling
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        //If we're here, it's not okay.
        ShaggyServiceStatus r = new ShaggyServiceStatus("Cannot connect to server", 999, "none");

        return r;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ShaggyServiceStatus result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        listener.onTaskCompleted(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `CurrentClassName.this`

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentClassName.this, LoginActivity.class);
```

`getActivity()`: used with Fragments

> Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

`class.this` isn't the same as `this` when you have nested class.

Comment: `this` in the inner class refers to the anonymous class

Answer (score 7):

If The activity that you use Called "`MyActivity`" then you can do the following:

```
MyActivity.this
```

This chunk of code will return the this "current" object of outer class

Comment: Simple and Clean. Thanks