# sendBroadcast after asynctask (started in widget onReceive) completes

Tags: android, android-asynctask, widget

**Goal**: update a widget view after `AsyncTask` completes.

**Scenario**: widget `onReceive` receives an intent from a user click.  This starts a networking operation in an `AsyncTask`.  An `interface` has been passed to the `AsyncTask` via constructor as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963705/1744123).  In the `interface` method, I'm trying to send a broadcast that will trigger the widget's `onUpdate` method but I don't believe that it is firing.

**Thoughts**: My best guess is that `onReceive` has returned, therefore the `Context` that I was trying to use to `sendBroadcast` is no longer available.  I was thinking that I could `get()`  the `AsyncTask` but I don't want to trigger ANR if the operation takes too long.  If I `get(timeout, unit)` the `AsyncTask`, I'm afraid that I risk missing the end of the task and the view will not be updated.

What's the best way to update the widget view upon completion of the task?

**Solution**: Turns out that I made a mistake crafting the `Intent` that I was broadcasting

Answer (score 1):

if you can hold a reference of the view to be updated,then just invoke `view#onUpdate`
in defined interface.if not,and you want to use a Broadcast to inform the view to update,so I suggest you use the [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html),then you don't need to worry if context exists now.Hope this could help you.

Comment: +1 for trying.  I had made a mistake creating the Intent that I was broadcasting, and that is why I never received it.