# How to get a JSON object data from AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>?

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have an MainActivity class. one Login class which extends AsyncTask. after execute Login class, it will return JSONObject to MainActivity like:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> getData = (new Login()).execute();
```

Now how can I separate data from getData?

my returned JOSNObject will looks like:

```
{"FirstName":"A","LastName":"B","ID":"09","Cell":"0123456789","Email":"abc@yahoo.com"}
```

**or do I need to handle these in different way?**

Comment: perform json parsing in `doInBackground` method..

Comment: I know that but I want to get data in my MainActivity class instead

Comment: you can store these `value` in your local variable in `onPostExecution` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this on `doInBackground`:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(StringResponse);

String FirstName = json.getString("FirstName");
String LastName = json.getString("LastName");
String ID = json.getString("ID");
String Cell= json.getString("Cell");
String Email= json.getString("Email");
```

Now you have data separate on differents strings.

Comment: I know this procedure but I want to get data in my MainActivity class instead

Comment: You can save that strings on `ArrayList` and past Array to another `Activity`, using...for example...a `Bundle and Intent` or `SharedPreferences`

Comment: ok thanks, if I follow your first solution then I need to start one activity from the Login class. I googled but unable to get solution for that. can you please try to solve my prob ?

Comment: You can make a `Splash Screen` search on google about that, it's easy. Tell me if you have any problem. =)

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from AsyncTask to your Activity you can create a call back method.

1. First create a Interface

   ```
   public interface OnTaskCompleteListener{
     public void onTaskCompleted(JsonObject jsonobj);  
   }
   ```
2. Then implement and override its method in Activity

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTaskCompleteListener{
     @Override
     public void OnTaskCompleted(JsonObject jsonobj)
     {

     }
   ```
3. And lastly pass data from your AsyncTask

   ```
   public class Login extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>{ 
   private OnTaskCompleteListener listener;

   public Login(OnTaskCompleteListener listener){
       this.listener=listener;
   }
   protected void onPostExecute(JsonObject obj){
       listener.onTaskCompleted(obj);
   }
   }
   ```

   I hope this is what you wanted. You can refer this question in case of doubts:

   [android asynctask sending callbacks to ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui)