# android httpsend response to activity from REST server

Tags: java, android, rest, httpurlconnection

I need to get information from a web REST server and because I cant call over network from the main thread I did it with AsyncTask.
I dont want to change the UI from the doPostExecute because I dont know which activity will call my class for information so I cant know what to change.
I need to understand how I can send a request and get the information back to use it in my java class of the activity.

Comment: use a `callback`. users of your class pass a callback reference to you and then you call that on doPostExecute.

Comment: Can you add an example? I tried to use a callback like this:
MyAsyncTask asyncTask = (MyAsyncTask) new MyAsyncTask(new MyAsyncTask.AsyncResponse(){

                @Override
                public void processFinish(JSONArray output){
                    arr[0] = output;
                }
            }).execute(URL + Repositories.get(repository) + data);

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui

Comment: I saw that and I took my code from that comment but still I cant use the response out of the delegate's block

Comment: you need to update your question with what you have tried, what is working, what is not working, etc. so that people can help you.