# onPostExecute AsyncTask not executed right after task.execute()

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I have an issue with AsyncTask

```
String latlong = "lat=48.8534100&lon=2.3488000";
city = "Paris";
getWeather w = new getWeather(latlong,this);
w.execute();
```

**This gs.alerter() should be executed after the onpostexecute, but it's execued before**

```
gs.alerter("thiss" + currentWeather); //This is a Log.i function
gs.cities.add(new City(city, currentWeather + "°", image));
initializeAdapter();
```

The AsyncTask class is :

```
public class getWeather extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

String latlong;
MainActivity obj;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json;

public getWeather(String latlong,MainActivity obj)
{
    this.latlong = latlong;
    this.obj = obj;
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?" +
            latlong +
            "&appid=APIKEY" +
            "&units=metric";
    json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
    return json;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    this.obj.setWeather(result);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

}
```

The setweather code is on the activity class :

```
public void setWeather(JSONObject obj){
    try {
        JSONObject main = obj.getJSONObject("main");
        Double initWeather = new Double(main.getString("temp"));
        int finalWeather = (int)Math.round(initWeather * 1) / 1;
        this.currentWeather = Integer.toString(finalWeather);
```

**This gs.alerter() should be executed just right after the .execute()**

```
        gs.alerter(this.currentWeather);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So the problem is that the code just after .execute() is executed after onpostexecute(). I want to execute it in this order : 
.execute()
onpostexecute() to affect the currentWeather variable
And then add City ...

Any help is needed.

Thank you all

**PS : I am a beginner in Android development :)**

Comment: You can implement callback mechanism refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9963705/847897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> put this code into a method:

```
public void methodName() {
    gs.alerter("thiss" + currentWeather); //This is a Log.i function
    gs.cities.add(new City(city, currentWeather + "°", image));
    initializeAdapter();
}
```

> and now:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    this.obj.setWeather(result);
    obj.methodName();
}
```

Comment: I just don't know how to thank you ! I've been stuck for hours trying to find a solution ! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create Interface

> public interface OnTaskCompleted{
>           void onTaskCompleted();
>       }

2. Your Activity Code will look like

   ```
   class YourActivity implements OnTaskCompleted {
   void someFunctionToExecute()
   {
     String latlong = "lat=48.8534100&lon=2.3488000";
     city = "Paris";
     getWeather w = new getWeather(latlong,this);
     w.execute();
   }
   // this code will be called after postExecute
    void OnTaskCompleted(){
       gs.alerter("thiss" + currentWeather); 
       gs.cities.add(new City(city, currentWeather + "°", image));
       initializeAdapter();
    }
   ```

   }
3. Your AsyncTask Code Will look like

> ```
> public class getWeather extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {
> String latlong;
> MainActivity obj;
> JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
> JSONObject json;
>
> public getWeather(String latlong,MainActivity obj)
> {
>     this.latlong = latlong;
>     this.obj = obj;
> }
>
> @Override
> protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     String URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?" +
>             latlong +
>             "&appid=APIKEY" +
>             "&units=metric";
>     json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
>     return json;
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
>     this.obj.setWeather(result);
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onPreExecute() {
>     super.onPreExecute();
>     obj.OnTaskCompleted(); // calling after postexecute 
> }
> }
> ```