# How come in AsyncTask doInBackground doesn't run but on second time it does runs

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So I am new with this and I need to call function that would run AsyncTask from separate file.

MainActivity.java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String res;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Asynctasktest newAsy = new Asynctasktest();



    res = newAsy.ValidateUser();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "'"+res+"'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

and AsyncTaskTest.java code

```
public class Asynctasktest extends MainActivity {

String Res;

private class GetFWork extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Res = "onPreExecute";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... param) {

        return "am i here";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String Result) {
        super.onPostExecute(Result);
        Res = Result;
    }
}

public String ValidateUser(){

    final GetFWork Fl = new GetFWork();

    Fl.execute();

    return Res;
}


}
```

So I need to get text "am i here", but I get "onPreExecute", which shows that on first call it doesnt do doInBackground.

Comment: This is a pretty primitive way to track the happenings in your app. Use `Log` or simply debug with breakpoints.

Comment: The first call should hit doInBackground(..)`. Add `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` at the beginning of `doInBackground(..)`, put a breakpoint and see if it hits the function.

Comment: The whole purpose of AsyncTask is that it's "async". You can't execute() it and expect to have the result inside the next line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how AsyncTask works.

```
res = newAsy.ValidateUser();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "'"+res+"'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

are both executed at the same time, and thus - since AsyncTask is asynchronous - the value of res is still "onPreExecute".

Answer (score 0):

Good point made by Wukash. Just to elaborate. When ValidateUser() is returning `Res`, there is no guarantee that the `AsyncTask` has completed running, since, its asynchronous, and runs off the main thread. Hence, in your case, it returns `null`, since `Res` never got updated.

If you require returning the value `result` to update UI or something, send a handler function reference as callback, and make that do this work.

Please let me know if you need some further explanation. I recall having had a similar question when I was implementing an `AysncTask` for the first time.

Comment: There are tons of resources available to set up a callback. [This is a good one that I followed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui).

Comment: I used that example and got it to work on my test.  So I need to use Asynctask to do different calls to php, I will have to pass through some parameters, then like in OnPreExecute I build the link and on doInBackground I do the httpurlconnection call and wait for the answer. Or there is a better way for that?

Comment: @IvarsAkmentins I think you are pretty good there. Maybe move the link-building to the doInBackground also, since you really don't need it to take place synchronously. A decent OOP approach could be to instantiate an `Asynctasktest` object, initialize a bunch of parameters that you need for the link-building, and offload everything to the doInBackground. This would result in a pretty solid design.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the super in this method

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Res = "onPreExecute";
}
```

Also remember that you cannot call the same AsyncTask object twice or you'll get this error:

```
Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
```

So the approach you have in your ValidateUser() method creating a new GetFWork() is good.