# android - recycle adapter not appearing in the view pager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a tablayout in ProfileActivity. And one of the tablayout will display recycleview of userlist that I retrieve from database using asynctask. I use getter method to return the userlist from asynctask class

My recycleview is in activity_user_view.xml and I set the adapter in the class that extends the fragments. I got no error however the tablayout doesn't appear in the view pager.

Here is my code

FragmentFriends.java (class that extends fragment)

```
public class FragmentFriends extends Fragment {
ArrayList<UserList> aList = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_user_view,container,false);// The activity that contains recyclerview

    PHPUserList phpUserList = new PHPUserList(getActivity());
    phpUserList.execute();
    aList = phpUserList.getArrayList();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.RVUserList);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(aList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootview;
}

}
```

PHPUserList.java (asynctask class)

```
public class PHPUserList extends AsyncTask<Void,UserList,Void> {

private Context context;
ArrayList<UserList> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

PHPUserList(Context ctx){

    this.context = ctx;
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://njtwicomp.pe.hu/listuser.php");
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
        }

        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        String json_string = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        int count = 0;
        while(count<jsonArray.length()){
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            count++;
            UserList userList = new UserList(JO.getString("Name"),JO.getString("Username"));
            publishProgress(userList);
        }
        Log.d("JSON STRING", json_string);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(UserList... values) {
    arrayList.add(values[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}

public ArrayList<UserList> getArrayList() {
    return arrayList;
}
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Incorrect usage of AsyncTask, please google it and follow samples

Comment: Which part did I do wrong? @StepanMaksymov

Comment: AsyncTask<String,Void,UserList> - logically string is url, UserList - must be returned and used in onPostExecute. Google it and find proper sample, on stackoverflow are tons of them.

Answer (score 1):

When items are added to a recycler view or a list view you need to notify the adapter that these changes have occurred which you aren't doing.

In `onProgressUpdate` you'd want to call `adapter.notifyItemInserted(position)` to tell the RecyclerView to refresh. To do this you'd need a callback or a listener in your AsyncTask because it doesn't have a reference to your adapter, and it shouldn't.

See here for all the notify calls you have the ability to use: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

Comment: So instead of returning the arraylist I should return the adapter?

Comment: No, the easiest way to do it would be to create an interface eg `ItemAddedListener` with a method `itemAdded(int position)` and have your fragment implement it. Then you pass the fragment to the async task as an `ItemAddedListener` object. In `onProgressUpdate` then call `itemAddedListener.itemAdded(position);`. In you're fragment this will call `adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);`. Note that in your AsyncTask you should store the listener as a WeakReference so you don't leak memory.

Comment: I am really blank about that. Could you give me link to learn about that?

Comment: No worries, try checking out this answer regarding the listener: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui