# Passing data from AsyncTask class to fragment

Tags: android

I have a problem concerning passing data from AsuycTask class to fragment class.
I have AyncTask class that get data from web service as a string and i want to pass the result from onPostExecute(String result) method to fragment but I always get NullPointerException, i've tried to make a static variable in the fragment class and make that static variable equals the result then i made Toast to show the result of that variable but the first Toast gets Null and the Second Toast gets the result!

Comment: It may be worth reading this post. Overall, static variables is not how you share data across android processes  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui