# Passing JSON data to the main activity

Tags: android, json

I am trying to connect my app to Mysql database using JSON and PHP. The PHP script returns a JSON array which determine the status of the light (true or false).

I tried to put the JSON code, which open the URL connection and get the status,in separate class. As a result, I can call it whenever I need to use it.

The problem is that the variable `res` does have a value inside the JSON class but when I tried to access it from the main Activity using JSON object, it is empty. Can any one direct me to the right solution to solve this problem?

Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public TextView t;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
  Json j = new Json();
  j.execute("http://127.0.0.1/web/test.php");
  t.setText(j.res);
 }
}
```

Json class

```
public class Json extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
String result = "";

public String res="";

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    InputStream isr = null;
    try {
        String URL = params[0];
        java.net.URL url = new URL(URL);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        isr = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "error in http conection" + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        }
        isr.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Log", "failed " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

JSONObject json;
protected void onPostExecute(String result2) {

    try {

        String password1 = "";
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            res=json.getString("status");

            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `t.setText(j.res);` is happening before Async Task completes execution. All UI manipulation should happen through `onPostExecute`

Comment: @muthana1990 yes you should do that and not return null in doinback ground as shown in my answer

Comment: i have updated my ans, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot return value from an AsyncTask** to main thread like that. There are 2 possible solutions

1) Make your text view as a global variable and in you `AsyncTask` override `onPostExecute()`. Inside your post execute you can update your text view with data from server.

2) make a listener (interface). Your activity should implement it and again override `onPostExecute()` and call that listener with the json data, finally in your callback update your views with data from json.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result2) {
    try {
        String password1 = "";
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            res=json.getString("status");
            break;
        }
        // UPDATE your views here, or make a callback to your class
        // via a listener and json data as a parameter and update 
        // your views there. Async tasks can cause memory leaks. 
        // Be careful with them.
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

(PS - Just a tip, dont catch generic exceptions, it's a bad practice)

Also, you can pass a string from `doInBackground` to `onPostExecute` which is decided on the 3rd parameter of your `AsyncTask<String, String, String>`. so since you are telling it that the object be of `String` type you can `return null;` replace null with a String generated in your `doInBackground` call.

```
public class Json extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        InputStream isr = null;
        String result;
        try {
            String URL = params[0];
            java.net.URL url = new URL(URL);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            isr = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "error in http conection" + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            isr.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Log", "failed " + e.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }

    JSONObject json;
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            String password1 = "";
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                res=json.getString("status");

                break;
            }
        } catch (JSONArrayException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

I did not run this code. Maybe you can check and verify!

Comment: I tried to use the first solution and I declared the textView as global variable but it does not suggest when I tried to use it inside onPostExecute().

Comment: so the catch is, you can use 1 if your AsyncTask is an inner class and 2 if its a different file.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui try this out, it will be fun

Answer (score 0):

execution is  in another thread and it may be execute the line    `t.setText(j.res);` before executing the request if you want to use the result in the activity you cand override `onpostExecute` in the activity not in the Json class as following :

```
new Json(){
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result2) {
//use string result as you want here   
}
}.execute("http://127.0.0.1/web/test.php");
```

and return your result in `doInBackGround` . not return `null`