# Bind spinner to dynamic list

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner

I am trying to bind a list coming from .net web-service. I am able to fetch list from webservice. But I am not able to bind list to spinner.

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<ValueText> lstRegions;
    private Activity activity;
    private String strRegions;


    AsyncCallWS() {
        lstRegions = new LinkedList<ValueText>();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Invoke webservice
        try {
            strRegions = WebService.invokeSelectRegionMasterWS("SelectRegionMaster");
            String[] regions = strRegions.split("\\},\\{");
            int i =0;
            for (String s: regions) {
                String strid = "", strName="";
                //logic to add data to list
            }




                Spinner spnDivision = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnDivision);
                MySpinnerAdapter adptRegion =
                        new MySpinnerAdapter(MyActivity.this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstRegions);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("myException", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So i can call `MySpinnerAdapter` from here, but I cannot use setadapter since this is working thread. `doInBackground` method has to be Void. So is there any way I can return the list? Or I can store list in something like viewstate (viewstate is asp.net). I am very new to Java and Android. And I really have no clue how to move forward. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui) that will return data from web service, after that in your activity you can set this data to adapter and attach it to spinner.

Example:

**AsyncCallWS.class**

```
public class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {
    @NonNull
    private OnTaskCompleteCallback callback;

    public AsyncCallWS(@NonNull OnTaskCompleteCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            //fetch data from web service
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                //here you can add all needed values which will be used in spinner
                result.add("Item " + i);
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> strings) {
        super.onPostExecute(strings);
        callback.dataReady(strings);
    }

    public interface OnTaskCompleteCallback {
        void dataReady(@NonNull List<String> data);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncCallWS.OnTaskCompleteCallback {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  AsyncCallWS callWS = new AsyncCallWS(this);
  callWS.execute("some_params");
 }

 @Override
 public void dataReady(@NonNull List < String > data) {
  //here you can set data in adapter
 }
}
```

Btw take a look into RxJava, using this approach you can easily make async task with few lines of code. If you interested in this I can add example with using RxJava

Answer (score 1):

You can declare static variable globally and store list in that variable and after post execute you can use that variable and bind value in spinner.