# AsyncTask returns null after calling it in another Activity

Tags: java, android, string, android-asynctask

I want to move my AsyncTask String value to another class with my constructor, my asynctask class is this

**GetTiempoGoogle.class**

```
public class GetTiempoGoogle extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Context context;
     String dateStr;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("https://google.com/"));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
                dateStr = response.getFirstHeader("Date").getValue();
                Date startDate = df.parse(dateStr);
                dateStr = String.valueOf(startDate.getTime()/1000);
                //Here I do something with the Date String

            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
        }catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {



    }

    public String getDateStr() {
        return dateStr;
    }
}
```

I have my getter there (getDateStr) which will return a google time date, so I need to access this value in my other class, what I did is this

**MyActivity.class**

```
GetTiempoGoogle Uconexion = new GetTiempoGoogle();
        Uconexion.execute();
        String Uconexionapp = Uconexion.getDateStr();
        Log.e("UconexionApp",""+Uconexionapp);
```

it seems that when I try to get the value is null... and I don't know why, I was trying a lot of things but I can't reach the date value.

Comment: you need callback mechanism for this (from `onPostExecute`), it takes time to execute the background task , won't return result instantly

Comment: That is because you're setting the string asynchronously. So when you access it, it's null because the connection hasn't returned a result yet. Anyways, the approach you have is wrong, as mentioned above you should use the onPostExecute. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to get value it's still being computed. You need to wait until http request finishes, return result from the `doInBackground` method and consume in the `onPostExecute` method.

Here is the simplified sample tailored for your code:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    interface Callback {

        void onTaskFinished(String result);

        void onTaskFailed(Throwable error);
    }

    private final Callback callback;
    private final HttpClient httpClient;

    private MyTask(Callback callback, HttpClient httpClient) {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://google.com/"));
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
                Date startDate = df.parse(response.getFirstHeader("Date").getValue());
                return String.valueOf(startDate.getTime() / 1000);
            } else {
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (Throwable error) {
            callback.onTaskFailed(error);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {
            callback.onTaskFinished(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And how it can be used in an Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyTask.Callback {

    private MyTask mTask;
    private HttpClient mClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        mTask = new MyTask(this, mClient);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mTask.cancel(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskFinished(String result) {
        // do whatever you want in activity with the result
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskFailed(Throwable error) {
        // warn user about the error
    }

}
```

Or you can do the same stuff using an embedded class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyTask mTask;
    private HttpClient mClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        mTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://google.com/"));
                    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
                        Date startDate = df.parse(response.getFirstHeader("Date").getValue());
                        return String.valueOf(startDate.getTime() / 1000);
                    } else {
                        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                    }
                } catch (Throwable error) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // handle the result here
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mTask.cancel(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you explain a little more what to do onPostExecute method ? thanks

Comment: i need a solution not an advice

Comment: @ArmandoBarreda, i added a couple of samples. Sorry for the late answer