# running a Upload file thread in android studio

Tags: android

i have a working Uploadfile() process, but im wanting to change it to run on a thread instead of main ui thread. i dont fully understand the types you have to pass i.e params, progress, result
my working code:

```
private void Uploadfile(){
            if (imageUri != null){

StorageReference fileReference = StorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));
                uploadtask = fileReference.putFile(imageUri)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                Toast.makeText(gallery.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Upload upload= new Upload(Filename.getText().toString().trim(),
                                        taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                                //create new database entry with unique image id
                                String uploadId = DBREF.push().getKey();
                                DBREF.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(gallery.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "no file selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

---

And the thread i tried to write:

---

private class Uploadfile extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(URL... urls) {

            if (imageUri != null) {

                StorageReference fileReference = StorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));
                uploadtask = fileReference.putFile(imageUri)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                Upload upload = new Upload(Filename.getText().toString().trim(),
                                        taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                                //create new database entry with unique image id
                                String uploadId = DBREF.push().getKey();
                                DBREF.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                            }
                        });
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        }
    }

Im not sure what to pass to the onPostExecute() function, any help welcome

Comment: please paste your code directly.
please do not use links or images to display code. Links are not always dependable and reduce the value of your post.

Answer (score 0):

At onPostResult you callback the caller so it know the task has finished.

[android asynctask sending callbacks to ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui)