# how to get the text that was set dynamically to a TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview

In my MainActivity.java i have set some text to a TextView, how do I get the text that I had set to the TextView

My Textview -

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/show"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="visible" />
```

ASyncTask -

```
public class fetchdata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private String data = "";

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://blablabla.com/hello.json");
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        data = bufferedReader.readLine();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
   MainActivity.show.setText(this.data);
}
```

}

MainActivity -

```
private static TextView show;
```

...... show is static

```
show = findViewById(R.id.show);
String data = show.getText().toString();
```

but data is empty instead of me getting "this is the text I want to get"

Comment: Have you made sure the show variable has the textview element? What happens when you debug your code?

Comment: Yeah, Its declared as global.

Comment: did you check if it is getting set ? I doubt there is no text set `onPostExecute`

Comment: Noo, there is definitely some text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the fact that the following two lines are together,

```
show = findViewById(R.id.show);
String data = show.getText().toString();
```

I'm gonna guess that they are in the `onCreate`, thereby resulting in empty `data`.

You'll need to wait for the `AsyncTask` to complete and `TextView` to have it's value set in `onPostExecute` before you try to get it in the UI thread. (You could use a [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963705/11016588))

Answer (score 0):

```
 class fetchdata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private String data = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://blablabla.com/hello.json");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
               return data = bufferedReader.readLine();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            show.setText(aVoid);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, your answer is correct but I have updated the question, can you help me fix this