# How can I use findViewById method inside AsyncTask?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, findviewbyid

I have an AsyncTask to execute while trying to connect the phone to a Bluetooth device, I want to change an icon from a button if it connects successfully

(I'm new to Kotlin programming)

[image: Main Code]

[image]

I would be very grateful if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this with line 146
val blueBtn=this@MainActivity.findViewById(R.id.blue_btn)

Comment: Still not working

Comment: create global button


  private lateinit var btn:Button
  and in oncreate{
  btn=findViewById(R.id.blue_btn)
 }


  then you can use btn in your class
  or pass to class conectedtodevice
  

 private class ConnectToDevice(c:Context,btn:Button)...
 
  use btn

  btn.setOnclickListener(){

  //click listener

  }

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention, that making changes from the async task is not really a best solution, since they are designed to handle only background jobs, so I would recommend sending a command from there to handle in the Activity

Still, if you want this, try changing you passed parameter `context` to be of type `Activity`, like `context: Activity`, and access `findViewById` by `context.findViewById(...)`

Comment: Can you explain a little more? (sorry for the question, but I'm starting programming in kotlin)

Comment: @GasparPereira async tasks are designed to make only background work without any access to the UI. Also, async tasks are deprecated and it's better to use services for background jobs, related article :https://medium.com/@varun93342/difference-between-thread-service-and-asynctask-in-android-d6e37960e56c

So, I believe it would be beneficial if you could make your code to be like that 

1. Async task handles only background job
2. Async task executes a callback to the activity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui
3. Activity handles UI work

Answer (score 0):

Replace **private** to **inner** class.